# Dataframe vlookup for dates in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) below where the index is the dates

```
              Alpha  Bravo
1997-01-02    21.14  699.25
1997-01-03    31.14  799.25
1997-01-06    41.14  899.25
1997-01-07    51.14  999.25
1997-01-08    61.14  199.25
```

I have another dataframe (df2) where the index are numbers

```
    Expire
0   1997-01-02
1   1997-01-07
```

I like to have the desired dataframe (df3) where

```
              Alpha  Bravo   Expire
1997-01-02    21.14  699.25  1
1997-01-03    31.14  799.25  0
1997-01-06    41.14  899.25  0
1997-01-07    51.14  999.25  1
1997-01-08    61.14  199.25  0
```

Can anyone kindly advise me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
df3['Expire'] = df3.index.isin(set(df2['Expire']))
```

Comment: I will accept your ans in 6mins, stackoverflow rules, thanks for your help :D